# start rtorrent at reboot

Tags: linux, debian, debian-jessie, rtorrent

How do I get rtorrent to start after reboot?

I tried to run

```
systemctl reenable rtorrent
```

and reboot the machine but there are no rtorrent process running.

I can start it using the following screen command:

```
screen -d -m -S rtorrent rtorrent
```

Here are my dependencies

```
systemctl list-dependencies rtorrent
rtorrent.service
● ├─system.slice
● └─basic.target
●   ├─paths.target
●   │ └─acpid.path
●   ├─slices.target
●   │ ├─-.slice
●   │ └─system.slice
●   ├─sockets.target
●   │ ├─acpid.socket
●   │ ├─avahi-daemon.socket
●   │ ├─dbus.socket
●   │ ├─docker.socket
●   │ ├─systemd-initctl.socket
●   │ ├─systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
●   │ ├─systemd-journald.socket
●   │ ├─systemd-shutdownd.socket
●   │ ├─systemd-udevd-control.socket
●   │ └─systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
●   ├─sysinit.target
●   │ ├─debian-fixup.service
●   │ ├─dev-hugepages.mount
●   │ ├─dev-mqueue.mount
●   │ ├─kmod-static-nodes.service
●   │ ├─networking.service
●   │ ├─plymouth-read-write.service
●   │ ├─plymouth-start.service
●   │ ├─proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
●   │ ├─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
●   │ ├─sys-kernel-config.mount
●   │ ├─sys-kernel-debug.mount
●   │ ├─systemd-ask-password-console.path
●   │ ├─systemd-binfmt.service
●   │ ├─systemd-journal-flush.service
●   │ ├─systemd-journald.service
●   │ ├─systemd-modules-load.service
●   │ ├─systemd-random-seed.service
●   │ ├─systemd-sysctl.service
●   │ ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
●   │ ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
●   │ ├─systemd-udev-trigger.service
●   │ ├─systemd-udevd.service
●   │ ├─systemd-update-utmp.service
●   │ ├─udev-finish.service
●   │ ├─cryptsetup.target
●   │ ├─local-fs.target
●   │ │ ├─-.mount
●   │ │ ├─boot.mount
●   │ │ ├─systemd-fsck-root.service
●   │ │ └─systemd-remount-fs.service
●   │ └─swap.target
●   │   ├─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a2ba1307\x2dc5ae\x2d4e84\x2d87d9\x2dca704d4103fe.swap
●   │   └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a2ba1307\x2dc5ae\x2d4e84\x2d87d9\x2dca704d4103fe.swap
●   └─timers.target
●     └─systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
```

I am using  Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie)

```
which rtorrent
/usr/local/bin/rtorrent
```

I edited the /etc/systemd/user/rt.service to this:

```
[Unit]
Description=rTorrent
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=none
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -d -m -fa -S rtorrent /usr/local/bin/rtorrent
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall -w -s 2 /usr/local/bin/rtorrent
WorkingDirectory=%h

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When I then run this command, and get an error.

```
systemctl --user start rt
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused
```

libpam-systemd is installed:

```
apt-get install libpam-systemd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libpam-systemd is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

and I rebooted the machine

```
uptime
18:26:03 up 5 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.06, 0.22, 0.13
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Debian package there is no systemd service/unit file for rtorrent. You need to create your own unit file. You can find examples here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RTorrent#Additional_tips

Comment: I created a file /etc/systemd/user/rt.service but then I get an error:
"systemctl --user enable rt"
"Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused"

Comment: You need the package `libpam-systemd`... Perhaps a reboot is necessary...

Comment: Was installed, rebooted anyway. Still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about *rTorrent* but according to information provided by your question, you should be able to create a service for *Systemd*. I tested it on my system (*Arch Linux*) and it did work.

First, you have to create a `*.service` file. I have added an example for such file below. Where to create this file depends on your needs. If you want to start rTorrent on boot, you should create the file under `/etc/systemd/system/`. If you want to start rTorrent on login, you should create it in `/etc/systemd/user/` (for every user) or `~/.config/systemd/user/` (for you only).

After creating this file, you should be able to start it. I will assume that you have named the file `rtorrent.service`, so the service is called `rtorrent`. If You have saved the file under `/etc/systemd/system/`, you can start the application by executing

```
# systemctl start rtorrent
```

as root. If you have saved it in `/etc/systemd/user/` or `~/.config/systemd/user/`, you have to call

```
$ systemctl --user start rtorrent
```

as local user. When it is working, you can replace `start` with `enable` to let the application start on reboot/login.

According to [this](https://forum.armbian.com/index.php/topic/470-systemctl-user-failed-to-get-d-bus-connection-connection-refused/) forum post, you have to install `libpam-systemd` before you can use user services on Debian. You may also need to restart your system.

---

I think your service file should basically look like my example below. You have to remove `User=...` if you have created a user service.

```
[Unit]
Description=rTorrent
After=network.target auditd.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -dmS rtorrent /bin/bash -c \
    'echo "$$$$" > %h/.rtorrent.pid && exec /usr/local/bin/rtorrent'

ExecStop=/bin/bash -c '/bin/kill -15 "$$(cat %h/.rtorrent.pid)"'
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c 'while /bin/kill -0 "$$(cat %h/.rtorrent.pid)"; do /bin/sleep 0.1; done'
ExecStopPost=bin/rm %h/.rtorrent.pid

Restart=on-failure
User=<insert some username here>
WorkingDirectory=~

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You have to run `systemctl [--user] daemon-reload` after changing the file. In my example above, I save the PID of rtorrent in `~/.rtorrent.pid` before starting it. To stop the application, I send `SIGTERM` (15) to rTorrent (using PID from `~/.rtorrent.pid`) and wait until the process stops.